# A problem with lambda calculus notation and semantics for function-valued functions

Tags: functions, notation, lambda-calculus

I would like to understand how to use the $\lambda$-notation to write usual (set-theoretic) functions, and if it is possible at all.

Here are my naïve attempts.  Assume that all variables are real-valued.
(I am using here the notation with "$\mapsto$" instead of "$\lambda$".)

**Example 1.**

If $f = x\mapsto \dfrac{1}{x}$ and $g_1 = x\mapsto 2x$, then $g_1\circ f = x\mapsto 2\cdot\dfrac{1}{x}$, and the domain of definition of $g_1\circ f$ is $D_{g_1\circ f}=\mathbf{R}\setminus\{0\}$.

**Example 2.**

If $h_1 = x\mapsto \left(y\mapsto \dfrac{y}{x}\right)$, then $D_{h_1}=\mathbf{R}$, and $h_1(0)$ is the empty (nowhere defined) function.

**Example 3.**

If $h_2 = x\mapsto \left(y\mapsto \dfrac{1}{x}\cdot y\right)$, then $h_2 = h_1$ and $D_{h_2}=\mathbf{R}$.

**My question.**

Consider now $f = x\mapsto \dfrac{1}{x}$ and $g_2 = x\mapsto(y\mapsto xy)$.
Then obviously $D_{g_2\circ f} =\mathbf{R}\setminus\{0\}$.

What is the simplest way to write $g_2\circ f$ in $\lambda$-notation (preferably with "$\mapsto$")?

*A problem:* my naïve attempt to write $g_2\circ f$ gave me, after $\beta$-reduction, the same term as for $h_2$.  However, $h_2$ is defined at $0$, but $g_2\circ f$ is not.

---

**Update.**

I have realized that a part of this phenomenon does not involve lambda-calculus.  The problem is that there is an infinity of ways to ["curry"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying) a set-theoretic function of two arguments.

For example, the function $f(x, y) = \dfrac{y}{x}$ of real arguments can be curried as
$$
\hat{f}(x) = y\mapsto\frac{y}{x}\colon\mathbf{R}\to\mathbf{R},\quad
x\in\mathbf{R}^* =\mathbf{R}\setminus\{0\},
$$
or as
$$
\hat{f}(x) = \begin{cases}
y\mapsto\dfrac{y}{x}\colon\mathbf{R}\to\mathbf{R} &\text{if}\ x \ne 0\\
\emptyset\ \text{(the empty function)} &\text{if}\ x = 0
\end{cases},\quad
x\in\mathbf{R}.
$$

---

**Update.**

I have stumbled upon virtually my examples in [*Declarative continuations: an investigation of duality in programming language semantics*](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/BFb0018355) by Andrzej Filinski (1989):

> [...] the uncurried forms of the following two ML functions
>
> ```
> fn x=>let t=1/x in (fn y=>t)
> fn x=>fn y=>1/x
> ```
>
> both compute the inverse of the first argument, but behave differently (the first may fail) in curried form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After learning more about lambda-calculus, I think I was looking for
$$
g_2\circ f = x\mapsto (x\mapsto (y\mapsto xy))(1/x)
$$
with [call-by-value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy#Call_by_value) evaluation strategy.

Call-by-value strategy seems to match the common mathematical (set-theoretic) meaning of functions.  Unrestricted $\beta$-reductions of a lambda-term can change its "call-by-value" meaning by increasing its domain of definition.

*Remark*.  To interpret lambda-terms as function definitions, I tried to follow common usage in ordinary mathematics.  It seems that my interpretation agrees with the one used by [Peter Landin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peter_Landin) in [*The mechanical evaluation of expressions*](https://academic.oup.com/comjnl/article/6/4/308/375725).

Comment: Don't use the same variable $x$ twice. Instead rename one of them; that's allowed and sometimes necessary in $\lambda$-calculus.

Comment: Why don't you replace $(x \mapsto (y \mapsto xy))(1/x)$ with $y \mapsto (1/x)y$?

Comment: @md2perpe, $x$ twice is ok here: i just copy-pasted the definition of $g_2$ to be clear (which is a closed term, so no need to ever rename anything).

Comment: I cannot replace what you suggest: it will give a different function ($h_2$). See my question.

Comment: How can $h_2$ be defined at $0$? You have the expression $\frac 1 x$ which is *not* defined at $0$.

Comment: It is explained in my question (Examples 2 and 3). Do we agree that the function $y\mapsto y/0$ is well-defined? (The empty function.)

Comment: How do you define the domain of a $\lambda$-expression? Why is $D_{h_1} = \mathbb R$ with $h_1(0) = \{\}$ instead of $D_{h_1} = \mathbb R \setminus \{0\}$?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/80193/discussion-between-alexey-and-md2perpe).

Comment: There is however a subtle question closely related to my original one: whether the definition "$f(x) = 1/0$" defines "$f$" to be the empty function, or is just invalid.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know whether "I am asking this question here because i am lazy to read through the whole Wikipedia article and to think." is an attempt at honesty or a bad pun. Nevertheless, I think you might benefit from the *hint* below.

**Hint:**

The composition operator $\circ$ may be defined as follows (in various notations, pick the one that suits you best):

- $\operatorname{compose}(f,g)(x) = f (g (x))$,
- $\operatorname{compose}(f,g) = x \mapsto f (g (x))$,
- $\operatorname{compose} = (f,g) \mapsto x \mapsto f (g (x))$,
- $\operatorname{compose} = \lambda (f,g).\ \lambda x.\ f (g\ x)$,
- $f \circ g \equiv x \mapsto f(g(x))$.

Get to work (and good luck)! :-P

Comment: Wikipedia article didn't help. It seems there is a semantical bug in lambda calculus: there is no way to write $g_2\circ f$. The formula i suggested reduces by $\beta$-reduction to $x\mapsto(y\mapsto\frac{1}{x}y)$, which is $h_2$, not $g_2\circ f$.

Comment: @Alexey Why do you think that $g_2 \circ f \not\equiv h_2$?

Comment: $h_2$ is defined at $0$, but $g_2\circ f$ is not.

Comment: I was trying to see how to use $\lambda$-calculus to describe and manipulate usual (set-theoretic) functions or computer programs, and it seems that $\lambda$-calculus sometimes fails to distinguish distinct ones.

Comment: Thinking in terms of computer programs: $h_2$ at $0$ yields a program that fails on every input, but $g_2\circ f$ fails at $0$.

Comment: @Alexey The untyped $λ$-calculus doesn't convey the information about domains in its terms. In fact you are using some weird extension of it that contains real numbers (any object in the the pure $λ$-calculus is a term, numbers, tuples, everything; it is similar to the fact that every object in set theory is a set). In such case you need to define what is a domain, etc. One of the most common solutions is adding the $\bot$ object to any type, and then e.g. $1/0 = \bot$; in such a setting both $h_2$ and $g_2 \circ f$ are the same function, with $(g_2 \circ f)(0) \equiv y \mapsto \bot$.

Comment: Does this mean that $\lambda$ calculus cannot be used to unambiguously write usual functions or computable functions?

Comment: dtldarek, i think i do not understand something or you are wrong: $h_2(0) = y\mapsto \bot$, $(g_2\circ f)(0) = \bot$.

Comment: @Alexey This is more complicated, I cannot claim enough knowledge to answer all subtleties of your question. For example, please note, that the calculation order makes a difference. Indeed, $g_2 \circ f = x \mapsto g_2 (1/x)$, and this is the simplest form if you disallow $\beta$-reductions other than the head position. Later, if you apply something and $β$-reduce the head term, then $(g_2 \circ f)(a)$ will become $h_2(a)$. On the other hand, if you choose to reduce the inside term $1/0$ first, you might arrive at a different result, that is $(g_2 \circ f)(0) = \bot\neq y\mapsto\bot = h_2(0)$.

Comment: @Alexey Regarding your last comment (I just saw it), as I just have written, this depends on the order of calculation.

Comment: @Alexey Compare this with [lazy evaluation order](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_evaluation) and [eager evaluation order](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strict_evaluation).

Comment: Well, i understand that this corresponds to lazy evaluation and eager evaluation, and i wonder if there is a way to distinguish between the two in writing, using $\lambda$-calculus or any other notation.

Comment: The formal solution is to define the semantics of your system and fully specify what calculation order do you use. The simplest way it probably to write a comment like "Consider the $λ$-calculus with $XYZ$ evaluation order." There are also some approaches in-between. Whatever you pick, you can always describe this with _natural language_ (i.e. regular text explanation). Consider also looking at typed theories, e.g. [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simply_typed_lambda_calculus) and [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependent_type).